# Is it possible to use a water molecule's expansion/contraction effect with heat as a motor?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, water, physical-chemistry

When water molecule is cooled, it is well known that it expands:

That's the reason the rocks in the desert explode in the cold of the night: the rocks have water inside that expands with cold and breaks the rock.

Other molecules compress when cooled.

Could this effect (expansion/contraction when heated) be used to moved an electron as a POC of doing work?

For example, water is a polar molecule, so it's mere expansion/contraction seems to point that it can move electrons.

Given there are random temperature fluctuations everywhere, it seems possible to use these micro contractions/expansions.

Does this break any known rules?

If we manage to use a diode equivalent, it would move electrons in only one direction.

Comment: Water expands as it freezes. Otherwise, it contracts when it is cooled. It is densest at 4 degrees C.

Comment: An individual water molecule does not expand or contract with temperature.  Rather, the net forces between different molecules change as the temperature changes (roughly speaking).  This causes the individual water molecules to be closer together or farther apart.

Comment: thanks for the correction @rghome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That's the reason the rocks in the desert explode in the cold of the night: the rocks have water inside that expands with cold and breaks the rock.

As @MichaelSeifert has already pointed in their comment, the rocks break not due to the expansion of individual molecules, but due to the fact that water freezes, forming a crystal lattices, where the spacing between molecules is bigger than in the liquid phase. That the density in a solid phase is lower than in the liquid one is indeed somewhat rare, and water is a commonplace example.

This doesn't mean that individual molecules do not change their size with temperature - at higher temperatures they experience vibrations, which are manifested in stretching of bonds and changing of the angles between the bonds. Thus, it is fair to say that molecules expand with temperature, since these oscillations occur at higher amplitudes (note that temperature is meaningfully defined only for a large collections of molecules, not a single molecule, but it means that individual molecule have on average higher energy.)

There have been indeed attempts to use molecular motion as nano-motors, ratchets, etc. - see, e.g. [*Brownian Ratchets: From Statistical Physics to Bio and Nano-Motors*](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article/85/7/557/1039654/Brownian-Ratchets-From-Statistical-Physics-to-Bio). A classical example of a molecular motor (although from a rather big molecule) is [Kinesin transporting ATP in cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motor):
[image]

[Well-known colorful animation can be found here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-uuk4Pr2i8)

Comment: thank you SO much for sharing this answer with us @Roger V.

Comment: @arod if the answer is useful, feel free to upvote or even accept it (but you might want to wait with accepting, in case someone provides a better answer.)

Comment: your answer was amazing. Already chose. Thanks. Could you please complete the answer by proving hurdles in this technology? I haven't seen it exploited and I don't know why.